# Unity with interface that extends another interface

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, inversion-of-control, unity-container, ioc-container

I have a class:

```
public class Foo : IFoo
{
}
```

and two interfaces:

```
Public interface IFoo : IBar<SomeType>
{
}

public interface IBar<T>
{
    DoSomething(T t);
}
```

We are using XML Config,the code configuration works fine, but the web.config doesn't.

The error is like:

> Resolution of the dependency failed, type = "IFoo", name = "(none)".
>   Exception occurred while: while resolving.
>   Exception is: InvalidOperationException - The current type, IBar`1[SomeType], is an interface and cannot be constructed. Are you missing a type mapping?

```
mlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/practices/2010/unity">
    <alias alias="IFoo"
        type="IFoo, Domain, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=e4bf38905880b60b" />

    <alias alias="Foo"
        type="Foo, Something, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=e4bf38905880b60b" />

    <container name="SomeName">
        <register type="IFoo" mapTo="Foo" />
    </container>
</unity>
```

Comment: Show you config too (small portion relevant to registering the type)

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov Done.  Cheers.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov I suspect I need to declare IBar<T> somewhere, but I con't see how in XML.  In code configuration it just works, I don't register IBar anywhere.

Comment: (I have not look into XML config for Unity much, so can't really answer - config looks OK to me). Are you sure if config is even read at all (i.e. does it resolve any other interfaces?) I don't believe you need to register `IBar<..>` (at least in code config you'd not do that).

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov I can see that it would have to be aware of that interface, so I can see that i would have to tell it where to look to find out the details of it.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov It seems insane that I'd have to declare `IBar<SomeType>` rather than `IBar<T>` in any case.

Comment: What type are you actually resolving? What code results in this error?

Answer (score 1):

I believe you're probably using the default instance of the UnityContainer since you didn't mention anything about using a named instance of the container.

```
<container name="SomeName">
    <register type="IFoo" mapTo="Foo" />
</container>
```

You're registering the mapping to "SomeName" instead of the default container.

Remove

```
name="SomeName"
```

Comment: If the OP could share the code that reads the configuration, sets up the container, and resolves the object, that would confirm. Based on the current info, however, I expect this answer is correct.